# Angular ng-slide-down module

Tags: angularjs, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use [this module](https://github.com/TheRusskiy/ng-slide-down) to provide slideToggle behaviour. Original code which works fine is

```
<li ng-click="showMe=!showMe" ng-repeat="team in teams">
  <a><h4>{{ team.name }}</h4></a>
  <div ng-show="showMe">
    <a ng-href="team/{{team.slug}}">{{ team.name }}</a>
      <ul>            
        <li ng-repeat="child in team.children">
          <a ng-href="/team/{{child.slug}}">{{ child.name }}</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

I've installed the above module with bower, changed the team view to

```
<li ng-click="showMe=!showMe" ng-repeat="team in teams">
  <a><h4>{{ team.name }}</h4></a>
  <div ng-slide-down="showMe" lazy-render duration="0.5">
    <a ng-href="team/{{team.slug}}">{{ team.name }}</a>
      <ul>            
        <li ng-repeat="child in team.children">
          <a ng-href="/team/{{child.slug}}">{{ child.name }}</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

and included the module in my app's dependencies.

app.coffee

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", [
  "ngRoute"
  "angulartics"
  "angulartics.google.analytics"
  "ng-slide-down"
])
teamy.config [
  "$routeProvider"
  "$locationProvider"
  ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix "!"

  $routeProvider
    .when "/",
      templateUrl: "/views/teams.html"
      controller: "Teams"
]
```

The view breaks when I add ng-slide-down as a dependency. I'm new to angular and taking over an existing app so any help would be appreciated. Also I have restarted the server, using grunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when "things break down" after adding a module dependency in Angular, it means that the required module wasn't loaded correctly before the module that depends on it.

I would check that the required lib is actually loaded in the browser, by inspecting the source JS files. If the application is using a concatenated file, e.g. vendor.js, perhaps by searching for a string that would identify the ng-slide-down lib like ".module('ng-slide-down'" ([source file](https://github.com/TheRusskiy/ng-slide-down/blob/master/dist/ng-slide-down.js)).

If you can't find it, it's a hint that grunt didn't include the file for whatever reason and you can investigate further around the build config perhaps.

If this is not the case (module is there and loaded), could you please elaborate on how the app breaks? Console output would be helpful.

Comment: Thx for the suggestions! You were right in that it was not being loaded. I've semi got it working except when the page loads all the divs which should be closed are open and immediately toggle close. I'll look for a solution so that on page load the divs are closed.

Comment: Awesome. As for the initial state, you could try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.